# Where can I find the list of price elasticities of demand for various industrial products, such as electricity?

Tags: economics

I am writing an economic piece and I would like to find estimated that are not older than 10 years at least.

Comment: Welcome to OpenData, please edit your question and provide more information as the question is vague in its current format and elasticity can be confused with materials physical elasticity. This would help your question reach more people and get it better chances to be answered.

Comment: @SuperKogito Okay

Comment: Elasticity estimates are scattered across different papers on RePEc and government websites. The relevant domains for Google search are `site:ideas.repec.org` and `site:gov`. For electricity, [`site:ideas.repec.org price elasticity of demand for electricity`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:ideas.repec.org%20price%20elasticity%20of%20demand%20for%20electricity) returns multiple recent studies.

Answer (score 1):

#### The US DoA: Commodity and Food Elasticities

The Department of Agriculture collected elasticities from different studies into a single database available at:

- https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/commodity-and-food-elasticities/

The creators grouped the data by country and commodity in summary tables. For example, dairy in the United States:

[image]

Or fish in Argentina:

[image]